# Possible to have a jenkins build fail tests but not fail the entire build?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have Jenkins job that builds an apk. I also have a gradle command that will run some tests on an Android device. I would like my jenkins job to be able to run this gradle command, but if the tests fail I don't want jenkins to fail the entire build. I just want it to mark the tests as failing and then notify people that the tests have failed. But failing tests by themselves should not mark the whole build as a fail. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Probably not the direction you want to go (hence why I'm not answering) but if you just need a stage to exit gracefully this may help; https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/885/cleanest-way-to-prematurely-exit-a-jenkins-pipeline-job-as-a-success

Answer (score 0):

[I believe you use the `ignoreFailures = true` flag in your gradle.build's `Test` task config.](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:ignoreFailures)

If that doesn't work, you can use Jenkins try/catch/finally:

```
try {
    // test step here
} catch (error) {
    // other steps if test step fails
}
```

Comment: This seems promising, but people wanted to be notified in the event of test failure. Not sure there's a way to do that via a try function.

Comment: If the test step fails in the try block, a notification step in the catch block can inform people.